# How to use a regex to find all curly-braces inside curly-braces?

Tags: r, regex

I'm using Zotero to create a BibTeX list of references from PDFs, and it uses { } around words whose case must be preserved.

> title = {Novel breeding habitat, oviposition microhabitat, and
> parental care in {Bokermannohyla} caramaschii ({Anura}: {Hylidae}) in
> southeastern {Brazil}},

However, some people in my team use Mendeley, which doesn't seem to know about this rule of BibTeX format, and the { } still appear in their titles after importing from the BibTeX file I've sent.

So I want to write a small script (in R) to remove the { } inside the main { } of the title (and other fields), so that the above line would, in the modified file, become as below.

> title = {Novel breeding habitat, oviposition microhabitat, and
> parental care in Bokermannohyla caramaschii (Anura: Hylidae) in
> southeastern Brazil},

I've tried a lot, but nothing works. What is the Regex to do that?

Comment: This really should be done by a parser, not regex. While it is possible to come up with regex that might work well enough with this one example, it is just as likely that a counter-example exists that looks similar enough to this but breaks the regex. There's a reason programming language interpreters don't use regex.

Comment: @r2evans Do you mean a parser I should build, or one already available? From the rules of BibTeX, there's no third level braces, so I can't think of a counter-example as you say. Any idea?

Comment: If you want tested efforts you need to supply data to work with that has the level of complexity that will be encountered.

Comment: @IRTFM There's no complexity at all. Scientific paper titles only have lowercase and uppercase letters, sometimes parenthesis, colons, and that's it. I've never seen { } in such titles, so I thought a simple regex may work.

Comment: If the offered test case will be on a single line then you can use the offered solution to pply to only ths lines that begin with "title =" and any other named fields for which you can devise unambiguous rules for this treatment. Caveat: These patterns are R-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a strategy that works if we can be sure that the "%%%" and "###" strings are not going to be present in the titles. First we change the first "{" to "%%%" and the last "}" to "###". Then remove all "{" and "}", and then put the first "{" and last "}" back in.

```
txt <- "title = {Novel breeding habitat, oviposition microhabitat, and parental care in {Bokermannohyla} caramaschii ({Anura}: {Hylidae}) in southeastern {Brazil}},"
txt2 <- sub("(^[^{]+)(\\{)", "\\1%%%", txt) # placeholder for first "{"
txt3 <- sub("(\\})([^}]*$)", "###\\2", txt2) #  "    "     for last "}"
txt4 <- gsub("\\{|\\}", "", txt3) # remove the rest
txt5 <- sub("%%%", "{", tx4) # put the leading and trailing ones back
txt6 <- sub("###", "}", txt5)
txt6
[1] "title = {Novel breeding habitat, oviposition microhabitat, and parental care in Bokermannohyla caramaschii (Anura: Hylidae) in southeastern Brazil},"
```

Comment: Nice! One can also use obscure Chinese characters, instead of "common" symbols like %%% and ###. For instance, the characters in the names of [a certain song](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-of-the-rarest-Chinese-characters-in-actual-use-in-names-and-place-names/answer/Hao-Tong-11)'s hero【龘䶛䨻䎱㸞蚮䡶䴞䴝䯬䬛䰕㹚】, dragon【㱎䖘䵈䶁䘔䶑䘓鋱䩳䵷㒪䪉䉥】, princess【䥸䝟䳮䟑䎘䫱䉷䰯䕈䟐䬝】 and king’s castle【䥰龘䰕䘋㽌䇁䵄䵻䬛蟿䆉㖀】. Most of these characters don't even show up on Zhongwen Popup dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a parser that removes just `{` and `}`, and only when inside a complete set of `{ ... }`. It doesn't pretend to be fast or efficient, but with reasonable-length strings, you shouldn't notice any lag.

```r
func <- function(S) {
  spl <- strsplit(S, "")[[1]]
  out <- character(0)
  inbrace <- 0L
  for (i in seq_along(spl)) {
    ch <- spl[i]
    if (ch == "{") {
      if (inbrace < 1L) out <- c(out, ch)
      inbrace <- inbrace + 1L
    } else if (ch == "}") {
      if (inbrace == 0L) {
        stop("unmatched close brace at: ", i)
      } else if (inbrace == 1L) {
        out <- c(out, ch)
      }
      inbrace <- max(0L, inbrace - 1L)
    } else out <- c(out, ch)
  }
  if (inbrace != 0L) stop("finished missing ", inbrace, " close-brace(s)")
  paste(out, collapse = "")
}
```

Demo:

```r
func('title = {Novel breeding habitat, oviposition microhabitat, and parental care in {Bokermannohyla} caramaschii ({Anura}: {Hylidae}) in southeastern {Brazil}},')
# [1] "title = {Novel breeding habitat, oviposition microhabitat, and parental care in Bokermannohyla caramaschii (Anura: Hylidae) in southeastern Brazil},"
```

It tries to be very specific, failing if either an unmatched `}` occurs or if the input ends while a `{` remains unmatched.

```r
func('title = {Novel breeding habitat, oviposition microhabitat, and parental care in {Bokermannohyla} caramaschii ({Anura}: {Hylidae}) in southeastern {Brazil},')
# Error in func("title = {Novel breeding habitat, oviposition microhabitat, and parental care in {Bokermannohyla} caramaschii ({Anura}: {Hylidae}) in southeastern {Brazil},") : 
#   finished missing 1 close-brace(s)

func('title = {Novel breeding habitat, oviposition microhabitat, and parental care in {Bokermannohyla}} caramaschii ({Anura}: {Hylidae}) in southeastern {Brazil}},')
# Error in func("title = {Novel breeding habitat, oviposition microhabitat, and parental care in {Bokermannohyla}} caramaschii ({Anura}: {Hylidae}) in southeastern {Brazil}},") : 
#   unmatched close brace at: 156
```

Comment: Great way to tackle using for loop

Comment: Yeah, thanks @onyambu, this is far from a vectorized solution but it works well enough and *safely* enough here that it might be worth the slight-inefficiency for the sake of completeness. I use something similar to parse SQL for the sake of translating between dialects, and it hasn't failed me in years of all-day-every-day use, and for that there are more than just simple `{`/`}` pairings to take into account.

Comment: It might be inefficient but can easily be optimized using c++.

Comment: The others seems to fail at somepoint. You should consider optimizing this. I hope OP accepts this as the solution

Comment: Even though IRTFM's answer may fail at very rare occasions (which may be adjusted according to the subject being researched, by changing the replacement pattern), it's easier to understand, debug and adapt for other purposes.

Comment: FWIW, this works regardless of `title=` or other tag ...

Answer (score 2):

You can convert matches of the regular expression

```
(?<!^title = ){|}(?!,$)
```

to empty strings (with `perl=TRUE`).

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vuB4Mr/1)

The regular expression can be broken down as follows. (I've shown spaces as character classes containing a space so that they are visible to the reader.)

```
(?<!            # begin a negative lookbehind
  ^             # match the start of the string 
  title[ ]=[ ]  # match 'title = '
)               # end negative lookbehind
{               # match '{'
|               # or
}               # match '}'
(?!             # begin a negative lookahead
  ,$            # match a comma at the end of the string
)               # end a negative lookahead
```

Comment: For R users, this is used as `gsub(ptn, "", inputstring, perl = TRUE)`.

Comment: This only considers title. But bibTex can have other fields too

Comment: @onyambu, I could not deal with other strings without seeing them.

Comment: It should work for any word instead of title. For instance: abstract, shorttitle, journal, author... (BibTeX fields are named using single words composed of ASCII lowercase characters). I tried replacing `title` with `[a-z]`, but it seems that [ ] cannot go inside a lookaround.

Comment: Rodrigo, like most languages, R (with `perl=TRUE`) requires lookbehinds (both positive and negative) to be *fixed-width*, meaning the length of the match must be known in advance. Whereas `(?<=[a-z]{3})7` is permitted, `(?<=[a-z]{3,5})7` is not. However, `(?<=[a-z]{3}|[a-z]{4}|[a-z]{5})7`, which matches `'cat7'`, `'goat7'` and `'horse7'`, is permitted. Similarly, you could write `(?<!^title = |^abstract = )`. Variable-length matches are permitted in lookaheads.

Comment: I see. A list of tags would be the best way to go then. But I prefer a solution tag-agnostic, considering that new tags might be added in the future, and undocumented tags may be used as well. So a different regex would be preferred (don't know if it's possible though). Or a different approach, like IRTFM's.